Cookies Missing in Middleware on Vercel
I'm facing an issue where my code works perfectly in my local development environment, but fails when deployed on Vercel.
Here’s a breakdown of the setup:
In my login page, I retrieve an access token from my API, store it in cookies using js-cookie, and then navigate to the home page using router.push. Here's the code:
const response = await postData("api/auth/jwt/create/", {
  username: values.username,
  password: values.password,
});

if (response) {
  Cookies.set("accessToken", response.access); // store the token in cookies
  router.push(`/home`); // navigate to the home page
}

Problem:
In my middleware, when I try to retrieve the access token from the cookies, it’s undefined on the initial redirect to /home. However, if I refresh the page, the accessToken is present and accessible in the middleware as expected.
Questions:

Is there a delay in Vercel when setting cookies that might prevent immediate access to them in the middleware?
Could there be any caching or other differences in Vercel’s environment affecting cookie access?
How can I ensure the cookie is available immediately in the middleware without needing a page refresh?

Middleware Code:
export default async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const response = I18nMiddleware(request);
  const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;
  const accessToken = request.cookies.get("accessToken");

  if (protectedPages.includes(pathname) && !accessToken) {
    // accessToken is not present initially, though it should be
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/account/signin", request.url));
  }
  
  return response;
}

Attempts to Resolve:

I've tried debugging by logging the cookie values immediately after setting it and before router.push, which confirms the cookie is being set.
I've also considered potential server-side caching issues but am not sure how to test or address them on Vercel.

Any insights or ideas for debugging would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
